# Autorun an MSI file on CD

Tags: windows, windows-installer

Does anyone have an example AUTORUN.INF which can launch an MSI installer automatically when the user inserts the CD.

I'm sure this can be done but I've been Googling around for ages and have not found any working solution.

**UPDATE:** I have an AUTORUN.INF similar to this but it won't launch the installer:

```
[autorun]
open=MyInstaller-1.0.0.msi
label=My CD Label
icon=MyIcon.ico
```

Comment: I would recommend writing some sort of program to check to see if user has your program installed rather than just blindly running the installer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try shellexecute= instead of open=

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=MyInstaller-1.0.0.msi
label=My CD Label
icon=MyIcon.ico
```

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question. After reading the articles linked by Ray, I have created the following AUTORUN.INF which works:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=MyInstaller-1.0.0.msi
label=My CD Label
icon=MyIcon.ico
```

The AUTORUN.INF file is placed in the root directory of the CD along with the icon file and msi file referred to.